# How can I remove all HTML tags in a string except for a few?

Tags: javascript, regex

For example I have a string

```
<p>
<div style="test">This is in a div</div>
</p>
<img src="">
<br>
final words
```

I would like to remove all tags except `img` and `br` so that the final string looks like:

```
This is in a div
<img src="">
<br>
final words
```

I tried using regex but I could not figure out how to do exceptions.

```
s.replace(/\<.+?\>/g, ""); //except certain ones?
```

Comment: Can't you use the DOM for this?

Comment: @elclanrs How to remove the tag but leave the content?

Comment: The content is a TextNode, you could try checking the tagName first, then loop its childNodes elements, and if the element has a textnode replace the element with the textnode.

Comment: @elclanrs Look at the first one.. div has a text node, you replace it and the text node is under p. and then u have to iterate again, and replace p with textnode. If you have more nested structure, you dont even know how many times you need to iterate thru..

Comment: It depends on why you want to do this; it is possible with the DOM and probably more reusable than a regex approach, but if it's just a quick dirty fix, then regex should be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right code is:

```
s.replace(/\<(?!img|br).*?\>/g, "");
```

Example:

```
var s = "<div>This is in a div <img src=''><br> final words</div>";
console.log(s.replace(/\<(?!img|br).*?\>/g, ""));

> "This is in a div <img src=''><br> final words"
```

Answer (score -1):

What about this small modification? It would ignore the ones starting with `<i` or `<b` ...

```
s.replace(/\<[^ib].+?\>/g, "");
```

Comment: If this works then why not ignore the ones starting with `(img|br)`?